# Powershell Output to my log location not working

Tags: powershell

I am looking to log the output of my script to a log file. But not able to get the output to a file.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

$server_names = Get-Content "E:\Bibin\Copy\complist.txt"

$Folder=$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))

$Logfile = "E:\Bibin\Copy\copy.log"

Function LogWrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)

   Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}

Foreach ($server in $server_names)
{
    $FileExists = Test-Path "\\$server\C$\temp\TEST\*"
    If ($FileExists -eq $True)  
    {
        New-Item "\\$server\C$\temp\TEST\$Folder" -type directory 

        Move-Item "\\$server\C$\temp\TEST\*" -Destination "\\$server\C$\temp\TEST\$Folder" -force

        Copy-Item "\\DC1NAS02P00\data\IT\CPS\Projects\NGNet\CpsServerUpgradeFiles\Upgrade Version 2.0\2003_Files\*.*" -Destination "\\$server\C$\temp\TEST" -Recurse

    }
    Else
    {
        New-Item "\\$server\C$\temp\TEST" -type directory

        Copy-Item "\\DC1NAS02P00\PDSdata\IT\CPS\Projects\NGNet\CpsServerUpgradeFiles\Upgrade Version 2.0\2003_Files\*.*" -Destination "\\$server\C$\temp\TEST" -Recurse
    }
}
```

Also I want some time gap between New_item and Move-item, since it is saying file is already in use ..

Thanks
Bibin

Comment: Describe 'not working'? Are there any errors?

Comment: I need to get output to log file . Date wise

Answer (score 0):

instead of using Add-Content use Out-File.

Also try robocopy instead of copy, this will wait for the locks to release before copying.

Comment: did you use out-file like i said?